# Rake aborted, Could not connect do postgresql: connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql

I am trying to execute the rake command on my brand new rails project with postgresql but I am getting this error:

> rake aborted! could not connect to server: Connection refused     Is the
>   server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting  TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?
>
> Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with --trace)
>
> real  0m3.245s user   0m1.668s sys    0m0.382s

This is my first rails app ever, whe I run `rails server` this is the output:

> => Booting WEBrick
>
> => Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`
>
> => Call with -d to detach
>
> => Ctrl-C to shutdown server [2012-06-19 01:17:30] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1 [2012-06-19 01:17:30] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20)
>
> [x86_64-darwin11.3.0] [2012-06-19 01:17:30] INFO
>
> WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4668 port=3000

Rails -v: `Rails 3.2.3`

gem env:

> RubyGems Environment:
>     - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
>     - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
>     - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/kinhow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
>     - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/kinhow/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
>     - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/kinhow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
>     - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>       - ruby
>       - x86_64-darwin-11
>     - GEM PATHS:
>        - /Users/kinhow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
>        - /Users/kinhow/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
>     - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>        - :update_sources => true
>        - :verbose => true
>        - :benchmark => false
>        - :backtrace => false
>        - :bulk_threshold => 1000
>     - REMOTE SOURCES:
>        - http://rubygems.org/

if it helps:

running `psql`

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory  Is the
>   server running locally and accepting  connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: have tried rake db:migrate first?

Comment: yes, same error: `Connection Refused`

Comment: give output of these command 'rails -v' and 'gem env'

Comment: check http://localhost:3000 without start server, it might be already started by using some bad thing

Comment: @vajapravin, just edited with info you asked. And nothing on localhost:3000

Comment: your postgreSQL is not working -- see http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql/errors.html#cannot-connect-local... might be your problem will be solve here, if postgreSQL is not working then use sqlite3 and check working or not.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to ensure that postgresql is running. Open a console and do a "ps auxw | grep post" and make sure that the server is running. You should have at least four processes running including "postgres: writer process". If you don't then you haven't started it. Even if you have started it, you must have it configured to listen on an appropriate port (127.0.0.1 and "localhost"). Did you edit the postgres.conf file and the pg_hba.conf files? If you did, did you restart the server? Are you using the latest pg gem? How do you start your server?

~Charles~

Comment: grep post was showing me nothing. I reinstalled postgres but didn't edit the .conf files. When I was giving up, I decided to go windows like and restart my mac. And guess what, IT WORKED! Postgres was somehow stuck